# Coldfusion scheduled task creating zero byte files

Tags: file, coldfusion, limit, publish

I am using coldfusion 10 scheduled tasks to create a txt file.
I checked the Save output to a file box and provided a path.

When I run the task, it creates the file perfectly if I limit the data.

But if I increase the data up to the point where the file generated pushes much past 50MB, I get a zero byte file.

I see no error in the scheduler log.  It says, Triggered.

It gets to the end of the code and cfmails me a I'm Done msg.  But the next chained item doesn't seem to fire off.

I've upped the file limits that I could find in the cf settings.
But I feel like I'm missing some limit somewhere.

Any ideas for me to try?

p.s.
I've already tried storing all the txt into a var and cfFile it to create a file, but that is taking way too long to process compared to this fast method.

Comment: if I run the cfm in a browser, I get this message when I increase the amount of data:

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 

javax.servlet.ServletException: ROOT CAUSE: 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

 coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:70)
 coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)

Comment: How much memory is allocated for the ColdFusion JVM? What OS are you running, and is it 32- or 64-bit?

Comment: You need to post some of the code that you are using to generate this 50MB file. Perhaps you can create the file in smaller chunks and use a `<cffile action="append" `